# Does Firefox has a maximum number of EventSource it can support?

Tags: javascript, java, html, firefox, eventsource

I'm currently developing a simple web dashboard using the class com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer. In this dashboard i can create a certain number of EventSource in a monitoring page.

By using that i've noticed that after just 6 parallel EventSource my browser stops "subscribing" to them. To prove it i have developed a simple toy example. You can find it in the following github repo: https://github.com/wellsaid/SimpleSSEHTTPServer

As you can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLjm6.png) the last two resources remains on waiting, while the first six starts receiving updates.

The output of my program is:

```
[Main] Creating the server object ...
[Main] Creating server context ...
[Main] Creating SSE contexts ...
[Main] Starting accepting requests!
[HttpRequestHandler] Received request from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47358: OK!
[Counter-Thread-5] Started
[Counter-Thread-1] Started
[Counter-Thread-3] Started
[Counter-Thread-2] Started
[Counter-Thread-4] Started
[Counter-Thread-6] Started
```

Which suggests that requests for resources 'counter7' and 'counter8' are never performed by the browser.

Finally, when i stop the server on the firefox debugger i can see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKwFC.png)

Does this mean there is some sort of maximum number of EventSource the browser (or the server) can handle from one client? In which case, how do i increase them?

UPDATE:
I think this is a problem of how the browser manages concurrency, since if i perform a request with curl on the resources 'counter7' and 'counter8' the server respond correctly: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGQlV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: [Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)

There is a maximum limit of HTTP connection between client, server pair depending on the browser.

Given the nature of my application i switched to a different model: using a single EventSource for each client. Then i send data in the following format:

data:key:value\n\n